# strong parameters with multi-model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_tag classification_code_rules_path do %>
  <% @classification_code_rules.each do |rule| %>
    <%= fields_for "classification_code_rule[]", rule do |pf| %>
      <%= pf.text_field :name %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

It sends what I want to the server:

```
Parameters: { ... "classification_code_rule"=>[{"name"=>"dasdsaf"}, {"name"=>"sfsdgdfhgf"}, {"name"=>"hfghfgjhgjhg"}], "commit"=>"Save changes"}
```

Since classification_code_rule is an array, I handle the params as follows:

```
  def classification_code_rule_params
    params[:classification_code_rule].each do |rule_param|
      rule_param.permit!
    end
  end
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

How can I handle this situation where the strong param is an array?

Comment: did you try `params.require(:classification_code_rule).permit!`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady that gives me "undefined method `permit!' for #<Array:0x007fe6b8cfda68>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
params.require(:classification_code_rule).map do |rule_param| 
  ActionController::Parameters.new(rule_param.to_hash).permit!
end
```

Comment: This worked without cancancan: params.require(:classification_code_rule).map(&:permit!). I'll try your technique and see if it works with cancancan.

Comment: With both techniques I had to add an except: load_and_authorize_resource except: [:create]  because of cancancan

Comment: I'll try to figure out why, because I'm using just these lines without any problem with cancancan